# Why does ASP.Net work without ManagedEngine being enabled?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, asp.net

In various places (https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2231761&seqNum=2, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/introduction-to-iis/iis-modules-overview#module-reference) I see statements that the IIS module "ManagedEngine" must be available for ASP.Net applications to function.  However, on Window 2012 R2 server this does not seem to be true - ASP.Net applications work even though ManagedEngine is not enabled.  It is defined in the `globalModules` section of applicationHost.config, but not listed in the `<modules>` section of that file or any other file I see in the hierarchy; and within IIS Manager's Modules tool, it shows as not enabled in the "Configure Native Modules" window.

Does ManagedEngine have some special treatment so that it doesn't have to be enabled like other modules?  Or does module enablement not work the way I think it does?

thanks!

Martin

Comment: ManagedEngine is the Integrated Pipeline module for .Net, and while it's a special case, I'd have thought it still needed to be loaded through globalModules at least. When in Classic mode, .Net is invoked through ASPNET_ISAPI.dll, like in IIS 6, so no ManagedEngine needed.

Comment: I appreciate your response.  ManagedEngine is defined in `<globalModules>`, but I can't find it in a `<modules>` and yet applications in an Integrated pool seem to work fine.  Mysterious.

Comment: There might well be a special exception there for Integrated Pipeline, as running ManagedEngine is what Integrated mode exists for - to integrate .net code in the IIS pipeline as if it were native.